# Can Angular App from Mobile directly write to Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I see that Cosmos DB is planet scalable.  So it means I can create multiple copies of Cosmos DB around the globe to provide faster response to users.

However, I wonder if a Web API is also require to write to Cosmos DB? If so we need to deploy multiple copies of Web API too.

My question is, Can Angular App from Mobile Device directly write to Cosmos DB?
(without an API layer in between)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can directly write to Cosmosdb using the **[`@azure/cosmos`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/cosmos)** npm package.

you can use it inside the angualr service as,

```
import * as Cosmos from "@azure/cosmos";

export class CosmosService {

    private static instance: CosmosService;
    private readonly cosmosHost = "<your_db>.documents.azure.com:443/";
    private readonly primaryKey = "<primary_key>";
    private readonly database = "ToDoList";
    private readonly collection = "Items";

    private client: Cosmos.CosmosClient;
    db: Cosmos.Database;
    container: Cosmos.Container;

    public items: Model.Todo[];

    constructor() {
        this.client = new Cosmos.CosmosClient({
            endpoint: `https://${this.cosmosHost}`,
            auth: {
                masterKey: this.primaryKey
            },
            consistencyLevel: "Eventual",
            connectionPolicy: {
                enableEndpointDiscovery: false
            }
        });

        this.db = this.client.database(this.database);
        this.container = this.db.container(this.collection);
    }

    async addItem(todo: Model.Todo) {
        const item = await this.container.items.create(todo)
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
        console.log(item);
    }

    async listCollections(): Promise<Model.Todo[]> {

        const response = await this.container.items
            .readAll<Model.Todo>().fetchAll();
        console.warn(response);
        this.items = response.resources;
        console.log(`${this.items.length} items received`);
        return this.items;
    }

    public static getInstance(): CosmosService {
        if (!CosmosService.instance)
            CosmosService.instance = new CosmosService();
        return CosmosService.instance;
    }
}
```

Here is a sample application with **[Ionic](https://github.com/sajeetharan/ionicosmos)** certainly you can use it with angular as well. But I would recommend you to use a web API in the middle

Comment: For me, it's problematic to use CosmosDb this way - you expose primary key in the client app, which is definitely not secure.
So far, I've only found following 2 ways with its own limitations:
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac,
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data#resource-tokens.